# Site migrated and now stash returns hashes not values... help!

Tags: ee2, stash

Have an EE2 site that is working fine.  Makes minor use of stash to store values for reuse elsewhere on a page.

I needed to move a copy of the site to a local server (MampPro) to allow me to begin EE3 migration work.  The basic migrated site works OK except that all stash instances are now returning hash values rather than content.  Here is an example - this snippet stores a channel field value in a stash and pulls it out elsewhere on the page:

```
{exp:stash:set name="std_summary"}
{std_summary}
{/exp:stash:set}
…
<div property="description">{exp:stash:get name="std_summary" process="end"}</div>
```

This structure works fine on the production site, but on the localised site it returns

```
{2fc38ed93cc9ea575c96a499a4f268d7807380034}
```

I've checked the configuration for stash, and it seems to be inline with the settings described in stash/wiki - (i.e. has a valid path and url for the stash cache, and rerun module updates) - but clearly I'm missing something in setup.

Using EE2.11.1 and stash 2.6.9.

Grateful for any ideas about what setting / config I've missed.

Comment: sounds like a permissions issue

Comment: Permissions for what...?  For good measure I've set the static-cache and templates folders to 777 - are there others that need to be set?

Comment: I've seen this before and it was, at least in my case, due to permissions of my cache folder wasn't writable by the server. Have you looked at any of your log errors?

Comment: OK - I've got this in the Apache Log - "... Directory index forbidden by Options directive: / ... /stash_cache/" - which is apache config setting - fixed this but made no difference.  No other error in apache log. :(

Comment: Hmm you can try reaching out to Croxton for any other ideas.

Comment: Is your stash_static_basepath setup to the correct location?

Comment: Hi Mark - I'm not sure where the 'correct' location is - but it is set to be a folder just below public_html (specifically /stash_cache/) - have confirmed that path is correct and the url is accessible (put a test file in that folder and you can open it via a browser).  But also `stash_static_cache_enabled` is set to FALSE - so should not be an issue either way.  I guess I'll see if I can get hold of Mark Croxton on the Slack channel.  Thanks for your help.